# Attribute error when loading object with pickle

Tags: python, object, dictionary

When i try to load the dict(that has as value arrays of objects) using pickle i get an attribute error with the palabra object(AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'palabra' on main' from 'C:...) and I am confused on how to solve it

to load it:

```
dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('diccionario.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    d = pickle.load(handle)

dict = d;

class palabra:

def __init__(self,pal,cant):
    self.name = pal
    self.prob = 0.0
    self.cant = cant
```

and  to save it

```
with open('diccionario.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
pickle.dump(dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I am willing to save it using csv rather than pickle but i dont know how either

Comment: What line is the error coming from?

Comment: from this line d = pickle.load(handle)

Comment: I am unable to replicate your problem. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you are experiencing. Please also specify which version of Python you are using.

Comment: However, I would highly suggest not using the name `dict` as a variable. That is the builtin name of the dictionary data type and it may break things if you define it to something new.

Comment: For some reason if i move up the palabra class it works, thanks anyway!

Comment: Try fixing the following and see what happens. Palabra's `__init__` is missing indentation. The first line of the whole code can be removed because it is overwritten.  `pickle.dump` line is missing indentation. Also change name of `dict` as previous said.